# IHttpClientFactory in .NET Core 2.1 Console App references System.Net.Http

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.1

**Tools**

- Visual Studio 2017 Professional (15.8.7)
- dotnetcore SDK 2.1.403

**Scenario**

I'm attempting to create a console app using the dotnet core framework.  The console app needs to make API requests.

I've read about the new `IHttpClientFactory` released as part of dotnet core 2.1.

The [official documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1) suggests that all I need to add to my project is a reference to the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` NuGet package.  I've done this.

**Problem**

I've added the `IHttpClientFactory` to a class, but visual studio only picks up the `System.Net.Http` namespace as a suggested reference:

[image]

**Question**

What did I do wrong :S

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*`The official documenation suggests that all I need to add to my project is a reference to the Microsoft.Extensions.Http NuGet package. I've done this.`*

That's true but in order to make things easier, you have to add  `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` as a NuGet package, in fact, you can delegate all the creation of httpClient instance to the `HttpClientBuilderExtensions` which add a  lot of extensions methods to create a `named or typed` HTTPClient 
here I have written an example for you

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;


namespace TypedHttpClientConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) => Run().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        public static async Task Run()
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();


            Configure(serviceCollection);

            var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            Console.WriteLine("Creating a client...");
            var github = services.GetRequiredService<GitHubClient>();

            Console.WriteLine("Sending a request...");
            var response = await github.GetJson();

            var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Response data:");
            Console.WriteLine((object)data);

            Console.WriteLine("Press the ANY key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void Configure(IServiceCollection services)
        {







            services.AddHttpClient("github", c =>
            {
                c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");

                c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json"); // GitHub API versioning
                c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample"); // GitHub requires a user-agent
            })                        
            .AddTypedClient<GitHubClient>();
        }
        private class GitHubClient
        {
            public GitHubClient(HttpClient httpClient)
            {
                HttpClient = httpClient;
            }

            public HttpClient HttpClient { get; }

            // Gets the list of services on github.
            public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetJson()
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/");

                var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                return response;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Hope this help

Comment: I think the code that adds Github-specific configuration should be a static member of `class GitHubClient` instead of an anonymous lambda in `Configure`. Just imo.

Answer (score 9):

The `Microsoft.Extensions.Http`, which is default included in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`  package, contains lots of packages which is commonly used for http-related code, it includes the `System.Net` package for example.

When you use something from the *nested* packages of `Microsoft.Extensions.Http`, you still need to reference them by the *using statement*.

So, nothing is wrong here. Just add a the `using System.Net.Http;` to your class.

Comment: I think you are missing the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` which make things easier

Answer (score 2):

Add this package reference in your csproj.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.2" />
```

Comment: This helped me, although I needed a later version number

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="3.1.3" />`