# send data from asp.net to console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, paypal

Hi I have two projects one asp.net and the other console and I have a controller which must send information to my console application to do a certain action. how to make my controller send data to my console app on two different machines and not on the same network.

Comment: Is the console app already running when it will receive the message? Or is it not running, and will the console app only be started from the ASP.NET process when it is time to act?

Comment: yes it is already executed

Comment: Normally controller does not sends data until you ask it. So a consumer sends request for data to controller and it sends back data. So if you need data in console application then use "httpclient" or similar classes to request the data form controller.

Comment: Here are few of the references https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918000/ihttpclientfactory-in-net-core-2-1-console-app-references-system-net-http